# Ubuntu 13.10 graphics issue causes blank screen and prevents install

Tags: drivers, system-installation, hp

I have not been able to install Ubuntu on my HP Envy 17 because the computer boots to the startup screen, but the screen goes blank during install.

I am wondering if there is a distro that has the HP Intel Graphics 4400 driver installed. Could I get an ISO with that embedded in it? There is a driver for the card, however I can't figure out how to put it on the install CD.

[Zorin](https://zorin.com/os/) is the flavor that I'm trying to install, but Ubuntu works the same way even after using nomodeset.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, can you see the logon dialog on the black screen?  I've had a similar issue with this chipset and is was down to the screen backlight not illuminating.

If this is the case, then at the initial grub boot loader, select the kernel that you intend to boot (probably only one of those if this is an initial install) and press 'e'.  This allows you to edit your boot options.  Scroll down to the line that begins with 'linux' and press the 'End' key (or use the cursor keys to move to the end).  Add a space followed by 'acpi_backlight=vendor' (no quotes, single underscore between acpi and backlight) and boot by pressing F10 or Ctl-X.

Hopefully, that will work.  If so, you need to edit your boot configuration to make this permanent.